# Passing javascript array as prop in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript array which I'm getting from a javascript class

```
export class BookStore {
constructor() {
  this._books = [
    { id: 1,title: "How to Learn JavaScript - Vol 1", info: "Study hard"},
    { id: 2,title: "How to Learn ES6", info: "Complete all exercises :-)"},
    { id: 3,title: "How to Learn React",info: "Complete all your CA's"},
    { id: 4,title: "Learn React", info: "Don't drink beers, until Friday (after four)"
    }
  ]
  this._nextID= 5;
}
get books(){ return this._books;}
addBook(book){
  book.id = this._nextID;
  this._books.push(book);
  this._nextID++;
}
 }
```

i then call the `books()` method to get the objects in an array.

I then try to pass them on as a prop

```
   const book = new BookStore()
console.log(book.books) //logs array
const books = book.books
console.log(books) // logs array

 <Route path="/products" render={() => <Product products={books}/>} />
```

inside the product component, I `console.log(this.props)` and it is an empty object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props) //logs `{}`
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <p></p>
      </div>


   )
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your questions? What is not working as expected?

Comment: are you sure that the middle snippet line 2 actually prints the _books array? You're not defining "books" as a member variable, and you didn't invoke the BookStore member function "books()" so not sure how you're getting the array to print out unless there's code you haven't provided

Comment: @Julian the `books()` member function is a getter, so it doesn't need invoking

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. While you provided code, it is not verifiable.

Comment: Please have a look into the fiddle (https://codesandbox.io/s/1qwy3kk5x7) it seems like you are props are properly passed like the way you want. Please have a look at the console, hope it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

EDIT: I was unaware of the get syntax for JS objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), thank you @Callam. The answer I provided is a solution without using the "get" syntax, by explicitly defining the member functions and using them like standard functions.

---

1. Instead of using the get syntax, just use standard functions and explicitly invoke the function to get the member variable you're looking for. Also would recommend you change the getter method into an anonymous function so you don't need to explicitly bind the instance to the function:

I'm assuming you can do this since I see the export syntax
    export class BookStore {
      ...
      books = () => this._books
      ...
    }
if you get a syntax however, you can explicitely bind the function in the constructor

```
export class BookStore {
  constructor() {
    this.books = this.books.bind(this);
  }
  ...
  books() { return this._books; }
  ...
}
```

2. Make sure you invoke the getter method after you've instantiated in your component:

   const book = new BookStore();
   const books = book.books(); 
   }

Comment: The `get` syntax is not a typo just in case that's what you're referring to – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get